# R creating a summary table based on date of another table with inequity join

Tags: r, join, data.table, cross-join, inequality

I have a table includes id, id_create_date and id_closed_date. Assume id_create_date starts from 2021-01-01 to today. In some of the days there is no id creation or id closing.

| ID | id_create_date | id_closed_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-01 |
| 2 | 2021-03-02 | NA |
| 3 | 2021-03-04 | 2021-04-11 |
| 4 | 2021-03-05 | 2021-03-22 |

I would like to have a summary table to count how many id created, how many id closed, how many id still open day by day from the beginning of the year to today.

| Date | number of opened | number of closed | number of still open |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-03-02 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-03-03 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-03-05 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2021-03-06 | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| 2021-04-11 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

To obtain desired table I created calendar table and I tried to join it with the main table. There is a work around using cross join in sql. But I am looking for a way to do this with **data.table** or **dplyr** or something different.

The data size huge so I used data.table to manipulate the data. However I cannot create the way how can count the ids based on calendar date with inequity join.

I tried many thing but could not find the solution.

```
test3 <- test1[test2, on = .(calender_date>= id_created_at),allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch = 0]
```

Only way that I found is loop. But table is too big so the loop does not come to end. The below code is loop version.

```
  newtable=data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  i=1
  while(i<=length(calendar[calendar<=Sys.Date()])){ 
    
    numberofids=length(unique(
      inbouds$id_id[which(inbouds$id_created_at==calendar[i])] ))
    
    numberofclosedids=length(unique(
      inbouds$id_id[which(inbouds$id_closed_at==calendar[i])] ))
    
    numberofPendingids=length(unique(
      inbouds$id_id[which(inbouds$id_created_at<calendar[i] & 
                                (is.na(inbouds$id_closed_at) | inbouds$id_closed_at>=calendar[i]))] ))
    
    
    subdata=cbind(as.character(calendar[i]),as.numeric(numberofids),as.numeric(numberofclosedids),as.numeric(numberofPendingids))
    subdata= as.data.frame(subdata,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    newtable=rbind(newtable,subdata)
    
    i=i+1
    
  }  
  
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  time.taken
  
  newtable=setNames(newtable, c("date", "#ofidOpened", "#ofidClosed", "#ofidPending"))
  
  newtable$date= as.character(newtable$date)
  newtable$`#ofidOpened`= as.numeric(newtable$`#ofidOpened`)
  newtable$`#ofidClosed`= as.numeric(newtable$`#ofidClosed`)
  newtable$`#ofidPending`= as.numeric(newtable$`#ofidPending`)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(your_data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using non-equi join:

```
DT[is.na(id_closed_date), id_closed_date := as.IDate("9999-12-31")]
d <- seq(as.IDate("2021-03-01"), as.IDate("2021-04-11"), by="1 day")
DT[.(d=d), on=.(id_create_date<=d, id_closed_date>=d), by=.EACHI,
    {
        nc <- sum(x.id_closed_date==i.d)
        .(num_open=sum(x.id_create_date==i.d), 
        num_closed=nc, 
        num_active=.N - nc)
    }]
```

output:

```
    id_create_date id_closed_date num_open num_closed num_active
 1:     2021-03-01     2021-03-01        1          1          0
 2:     2021-03-02     2021-03-02        1          0          1
 3:     2021-03-03     2021-03-03        0          0          1
 4:     2021-03-04     2021-03-04        1          0          2
 5:     2021-03-05     2021-03-05        1          0          3
 6:     2021-03-06     2021-03-06        0          0          3
 7:     2021-03-07     2021-03-07        0          0          3
 8:     2021-03-08     2021-03-08        0          0          3
 9:     2021-03-09     2021-03-09        0          0          3
10:     2021-03-10     2021-03-10        0          0          3
11:     2021-03-11     2021-03-11        0          0          3
12:     2021-03-12     2021-03-12        0          0          3
13:     2021-03-13     2021-03-13        0          0          3
14:     2021-03-14     2021-03-14        0          0          3
15:     2021-03-15     2021-03-15        0          0          3
16:     2021-03-16     2021-03-16        0          0          3
17:     2021-03-17     2021-03-17        0          0          3
18:     2021-03-18     2021-03-18        0          0          3
19:     2021-03-19     2021-03-19        0          0          3
20:     2021-03-20     2021-03-20        0          0          3
21:     2021-03-21     2021-03-21        0          0          3
22:     2021-03-22     2021-03-22        0          1          2
23:     2021-03-23     2021-03-23        0          0          2
24:     2021-03-24     2021-03-24        0          0          2
25:     2021-03-25     2021-03-25        0          0          2
26:     2021-03-26     2021-03-26        0          0          2
27:     2021-03-27     2021-03-27        0          0          2
28:     2021-03-28     2021-03-28        0          0          2
29:     2021-03-29     2021-03-29        0          0          2
30:     2021-03-30     2021-03-30        0          0          2
31:     2021-03-31     2021-03-31        0          0          2
32:     2021-04-01     2021-04-01        0          0          2
33:     2021-04-02     2021-04-02        0          0          2
34:     2021-04-03     2021-04-03        0          0          2
35:     2021-04-04     2021-04-04        0          0          2
36:     2021-04-05     2021-04-05        0          0          2
37:     2021-04-06     2021-04-06        0          0          2
38:     2021-04-07     2021-04-07        0          0          2
39:     2021-04-08     2021-04-08        0          0          2
40:     2021-04-09     2021-04-09        0          0          2
41:     2021-04-10     2021-04-10        0          0          2
42:     2021-04-11     2021-04-11        0          1          1
    id_create_date id_closed_date num_open num_closed num_active
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("ID id_create_date  id_closed_date
1   2021-03-01  2021-03-01
2   2021-03-02  NA
3   2021-03-04  2021-04-11
4   2021-03-05  2021-03-22")
cols <- c("id_create_date", "id_closed_date")
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), .SDcols=cols]
```

Comment: thanks for your support. Actually I had simplified a bit my case to ask the community but now I am stuck on something. What if there are other columns like country, city, cluster etc. in addition to date? How can it be .(d=d) ?  I mean it will summarize the table not only by date also by other breakdowns.

Comment: you can use `CJ` and add those columns in `on` as well. best is if you can provide a minimal sample dataset and desired output.